# Monkey Patching SASS/SCSS

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

On a website that is built with Foundation, I would like to be able to set the color palette dynamically after the SASS has been processed during bundle compilation.

CSS variables seem to be the best option for this.

While this works well for basic cases, I run into issues when applying this approach to the Foundation palette, as it is using color functions that don't play well with CSS variables:

```
SassError: $color: var(--primary-color) is not a color.
   ╷
21 │   $rgba: red($color), green($color), blue($color);
   │          ^^^^^^^^^^^   
   ╵
  node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_color.scss 21:10          color-luminance()        
  node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_color.scss 45:16          color-contrast()         
  node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_color.scss 66:14          color-pick-contrast()    
  node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/_button.scss 190:13  button-style()
  node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/_button.scss 169:5   button-fill-style()
  node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/_button.scss 378:13  foundation-button()
  node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss 112:3           foundation-everything()  
  src/scss/index.scss 4:1
```

So, ideally I would change the `button-style` mixin to use an approach that doesn't use `color-pick-contrast()` as this function will not work with variables.

Setting aside the specific changes required to `button-style`, the general question arises:

How do I make that change?

`button-style` is part of the Foundation code-base and it doesn't seem very appealing to maintain a patch-set on top of Foundation.

So is there any way, that I can monkey-patch Foundation's `button-style` from my code and make this work in a maintainable fashion?

Comment: No answer here, but I just tried and failed to get a good monkey patch using the methods I know. The Sass API's `functions` doesn't override existing functions, the API's `includePaths` are used after trying a relative import, sass-loader's `additionalData` only works on the entry point, and the `meta` built-in module for replacing the `module-functions`/`variables` lets you mutate the map, but not affect the module.